# Why did they build the Death Star in space, instead of out of an asteroid?

Tags: star-wars, death-star

The sheer logistics of a 160-km wide metal rock being mined, then all that material being moved to another location just to build a 160-km wide artificial moon somewhere else made me ask this question.

**Were there any engineering reasons why the Death Star wasn't built in situ,  from whatever object they got the materials from?**

[image]

Comment: Okay, changing some words

Comment: You might also want to note that, mindful of the failings of prior Death Stars, the First Order built their [superweapon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller_Base) out of a planetoid.

Comment: I've done a very big edit to try to make your question a bit clearer. Close vote retracted.

Comment: @Valorum that shows my ignorance but doesn't tell why deathstar and its bigger version 2 built in space :)

Comment: Indeed. That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer :-)

Comment: Isn't this like asking why a ship isn't built from a teeny tiny island?  An asteroid is already in space - what would be the point?

Comment: @Tim - It's more like asking why someone would build an aircraft carrier instead of slapping an airstrip onto an existing island, with the added wrinkle that the island can be made mobile.

Comment: @Tim its like asking why someone fill sands in ocean shore to build an artificial island (like world-islands) instead of building things on real islands LOL

Comment: @Valorum - oh, I see.  You're asking why not just turn an asteroid into the Death Star.  That's not clear from the question.
Probably because an asteroid would be unstable, and you might as well build a big ship since it'd be about the same effort.

Comment: Probably because when you have to blast away a billion tons of rock to build the next hangar bay, you don't want all those stray boulders careening into your construction crews.

Comment: They could use the force to shield those blasted rocks though

Comment: In Legends, they built at least one Death Star prototype out of an asteroid; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eye_of_Palpatine

Comment: If it makes you feel better, that's what they did for Starkiller Base; they built it out of a planet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly because real asteroids have different compositions.  No doubt many different materials would be used in the Death Star, some very common in asteroids and others very rare in asteroids.

Depending on the composition of an asteroid and the composition of the Death Star an asteroid might be made of 2 percent Death Star building materials or 20 percent Death Star building materials or 84.6 percent Death Star building materials or 0.04 percent Death Star building materials or some other percentage.

The other matter in the asteroid that can't be use to build the Death Star has to be thrown away.

So instead of building the Death Star out of a single asteroid it makes more sense to mine many asteroids of different types for the different needed materials and transport those materials to space or planetary refineries and factories to convert them into Death Star parts and then take them to where the Death Star is being built floating in space.